# Status of Paper Money as Currency

Tags: money, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, gold, kiddushin-eirusin

According to this question, [Maasar Sheni cannot be redeemed using paper money](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37516/redeeming-maaser-sheini-on-paper-money). That certainly seems to be the common assumption, but is that discussed anywhere? Is paper money the same as banknotes, when the money is not used to be traded in for precious metals at the bank anymore?

In what other areas of halakha is our modern from of currency not considered money? Can one use it for Kiddushin (as money, not hanaah/shaveh kesef)? For kinyan kesef (to acquire land)?

What's the reason why or why not paper money, which isn't backed by silver or gold, would be or would not be considered money?

Comment: Possibly related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12112/

Comment: I counted 6 questions here: 1. That certainly seems to be the common assumption, but is that discussed anywhere? 2. Is paper money the same as banknotes, when the money is not used to be traded in for precious metals at the bank anymore? 3. In what other areas of halakha is our modern from of currency not considered money? 4. Can one use it for Kiddushin (as money, not hanaah/shaveh kesef)? 5. For kinyan kesef (to acquire land)? 6. What's the reason why or why not paper money, which isn't backed by silver or gold, would be or would not be considered money?

Answer (score 7):

[Chatam Sofer Yoreh De'ah 134](https://www.sefaria.org/Responsa_Chatam_Sofer,_Yoreh_De'ah.134.23?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes pretty definitively that **paper money is considered money for virtually all purposes**:

> אבל גדר המטבע הוא שגזר המלך עליו שתצא ומי שממאן מלמכר וליקח באותו המטבע יחייב ראשו למלכות ... **ואין חילוק אם יהי' זהב או כסף או נייר**
>
> The definition of a coin is that which the king has decreed to be legal tender such that anyone who refuses to buy or sell with that coin is held liable to king .. **and there is no difference if it is made of gold or silver or paper**.

He then [goes on to rule](https://www.sefaria.org/Responsa_Chatam_Sofer,_Yoreh_De'ah.134.26?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> והנה לפ"ז אין ספק אצלי דהני באנק"א המה כסף גמור **אפי' לקדש אשה** ... וא"כ ממילא דהוי כסף **לפדות הקדשות ומעשר שני**
>
> Therefore, to me there is no doubt that banknotes are completely identical to money, **even for the purposes of *kiddushin*** ... and if so they are also considered money **to redeem *hekdesh* and *ma'aser sheni***.

The one case he is unsure about is whether paper money works for redeeming a firstborn son where one is "buying the child back from G-d", and therefore maybe needs to use currency as defined by G-d, rather than humans.

---

As noted in the question, common practice is not to use paper money to redeem *ma'aser sheni*, unlike this view of Chatam Sofer.

However, as noted by R. Chaim Kanievsky in [Derech Emunah Hilchot Ma'aser Sheni Ch. 4, 60](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49070&st=&pgnum=267):

> ולפי זה **פודין אף במטבע של נייר** אלא שאין עושין מעשה במה שלא שמענו מרבותינו ואפשר דלא ליתי לזלזולי בפדיונו אין לעשות כן וצ"ע
>
> According to this **one can redeem [*ma'aser sheni*] even with paper "coins"**, but we are loathe to carry out a ruling in practice which we have not heard from our Rabbis, and it is also possible that we don't do this [i.e. use paper money] so as not to cheapen the redemption process, and the matter requires further study.

Comment: It wasn't obvious to me that the designs on paper money count as a צורה when they don't have any visible depth to them.

Comment: @Heshy. Interesting. Any reason for assuming that צורה would imply some kind of depth?

Comment: Well apparently not if the Chasam Sofer says it doesn't.  I guess I was coming from examples like ויצר אתו בחרט (one of the ways Rashi says it) but of course that doesn't prove it has to be a 3D picture.

Comment: @joelk perhaps depth is needed because מטבע means sunken (ie an imprint)

Comment: Please note that in the era of the Chatam Sofer, banknotes were convertible, i.e. you could go into the national bank, and get coins from silver (or golden), and it was usually written on the banknote itself. See this Austrian banknote for example *(Die privilegierte österreichische National-bank bezahlt dem Überbringer gegen diese Anweisung Zehn Gulden Silbermünze nach dem Conventions-Fusse):* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austro-Hungarian_gulden#/media/File:AUS-A71-Austria-10_Gulden_(1841).jpg

Comment: @Kazibácsi That's true. As noted by R. Asher Weiss (quoted in wfb's answer) that means that today's paper money is even less like a _shtar_ and more like something possessing intrinsic value. Presumably, if Chatam Sofer held that his banknotes were not a _shtar_ but considered a 'coin', he would certainly say the same about our banknotes

Comment: It's just interesting that due the lack of the convertibility, in economics we call the current banknotes as money without intrinsic value... :-)

Answer (score 6):

**Rav Asher Weiss** has a [teshuvah](http://www.torahbase.org/%D7%A4%D7%93%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%94%D7%91%D7%9F-%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9B%D7%A1%D7%A3-%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%95/) about use of paper money for pidyon ha-ben. The basis for the question is that the Gemara ([Bechoros 51a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bekhorot.51a.7-9?lang=bi)) states that one may not use shtaros for pidyon ha-ben because they are not "themselves money" (gufan mamon). He cites four views about the status of paper money today:

> הנה נחלקו האחרונים בדין כסף בזה"ז אם הוי גופו ממון לענין פדיון הבן,
>   פדיון הקדש, מע"ש, אונאה ושומרין. דבכל הני איתמעטו שטרות משום דאין גופן
>   ממון, ויש בזה ד' דרכים.
>
> בשו"ת **חת"ס** יו"ד סי' קל"ד מובאים דברי השואל, שכתב לחוש דאף דכסף בזמנינו
>   הוי כעין שטר במהותו שהרי אין ערך עצמי בשטרי הניר מ"מ הוי כגופו ממון
>   משום דכל שטר שכל המוציאו יכול לגבותו ולא רק אדם מסויים שהוא המלוה דינו
>   כשוה כסף וכגופו ממון. אך החת"ס דחה דבריו דכיון דמ"מ כל ערך השטר רק
>   משום הראיה שבו שעל ידו אפשר לגבות מן החייב, דינו כשטר וכאין גופו ממון.
>   אך מטעם אחר כתב החת"ס דכסף בזמנינו הוי גופו ממון ולא מיבעי' מטבעות אלא
>   אף שטרי כסף, משום דדינא דמלכותא הוא שיש לכבד כסף הממשלה ומשום דינא
>   דמלכותא נעשה כאילו יש בו ערך עצמי עי"ש.
>
> ובשו"ת **עונג יו"ט** יו"ד סי' ק"ב חלק על החת"ס ונקט דמטבעות שיש בהם ערך
>   עצמי מצד המתכת שבהם, הוי גופו ממון אף שעיקר ערכם אינו משום המתכת אלא
>   משום הטיבוע ומצד היותם כסף היוצא דמ"מ יש בהם ערך עצמי וטבעי ומה דשוה
>   טפי משום היותם כסף מוכר מטעם המדינה אין בכך כלום והרי זה כסודרא דרב
>   כהנא וככל דבר שערכו עולה ע"י גורמים שונים של היצע וביקוש, אך שטרות כסף
>   שאין להם ערך עצמי כלל וכל שווים רק משום היותם כסף הוי בכלל אין גופו
>   ממון ופסולים לפה"ב.
>
> והנה אף **שהחת"ס** נקט דגם שטרי כסף הוי גופו ממון לכל דיני תורה מ"מ לגבי
>   פה"ב נסתפק דכיון דהוי מצוה בין אדם למקום צריך שווי בעצם ודינא דמלכותא
>   אין לו משמעות כלפי מעלה עי"ש. אך מעודי תמוהה היתה בעיני סברא זו דמהי"ת
>   לחלק בין פדיון הקדש ומע"ש לפדיון הבן, דאף אם בהקדש אפשר דהוי גדר קנין
>   מהגזבר (וגם זה לא מילתא דפשיטא היא והארכתי במק"א) פדיון מע"ש למ"ד מע"ש
>   ממון גבוה ודאי לא הוי גדר קנין, אך ביותר יש לתמוה בעצם הסברא לחלק בין
>   בן אדם לחבירו ובן אדם למקום דמה לן לחלק בין דין לדין וממ"נ אם שווי זה
>   הוי גופו ממון ליהני לכל דבר, וצע"ג בדברי רבן של ישראל החת"ס.
>
> **והחזו"א** ביו"ד סי' ע"ב אות ח'- י' ביאר בארוכה שיטתו בכל דין כסף בזמה"ז,
>   והסיק דאף דיסוד הכסף הוי כהתחייבות המימשל לפרוע תמורת כל שטרות הכסף
>   מ"מ עיקר שווי הכסף בשימושו ולכן הוי גופו ממון, ולא משום דינא דמלכותא
>   אלא משום מציאות החיים דשימושו בכח הקניה והפרעון הוא שמקנה לו ערכו ולא
>   הראיה שבו. ומשום כך הוי גופו ממון לכל דבר וגם לפה"ב.
>
> וכך נראה עיקר להלכה ובפרט בזמנינו שמערכות הכלכלה העולמית השתנו לגמרי
>   דרק לפני עשרות שנים, לא רק בימי החת"ס והעיו"ט אלא אף בימי החזו"א שטרי
>   הכסף של מדינות היו נשענים על כסף וזהב וכדו' שבאוצרות המדינה והיה מעין
>   התחייבות של כל מדינה ומדינה לפרוע לכל מי שיבא ויבקש תמורת כספו, אבל
>   בזמנינו אין כל קשר בין כמות שטרי הכסף של מדינה לבין כסף וזהב
>   שבאוצרותיה ומה שקובע את כמות הכסף שמדינה מדפיסה אינו אלא ההשפעה שיש
>   לכמות הכסף על מערכות המשק דריבוי הכסף גורם עליית מחירים (אינפלציה),
>   וא"כ מסתבר דאין שטרי הכסף בכלל ראיה כלל ואינם דומים לשטרות וגופו ממון
>   ממש הם. ואף דפשוט דגם בזה"ז אין מטבע נעשה חליפין משום דדעתיה אצורתא
>   מ"מ הוי גופו ממון ואין זה ענין אצל זה, דאין הכסף שבזמנינו שטר וראיה
>   לגבות כלום מהמדינה וכל ערכו תלוי רק בכח הקניה שבו ופשוט לכאורה דהוי
>   גופו ממון.

In short:

- according to the **Chasam Sofer**, paper money has the status of gufo mamon based on dina de-malchusa.
- according to the **Oneg Yom Tov**, it does not have the status of gufo mamon

  - (and the Chasam Sofer may agree with the Oneg Yom Tov for a special reason regarding pidyon ha-ben)
- according to the **Chazon Ish** it has the status of gufo mamon, not because of dina de-malchusa but because in reality paper money has value.

Rav Asher Weiss agrees with the Chazon Ish, and notes that nowadays, [unlike until the recent past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_certificate), paper money is not backed by silver. Thus it is more likely to be considered to have inherent value and is less like a shtar.

Comment: This reminds me a bit of the discussion of use value vs. exchange value in the first chapter(s) of Marx' Das Kapital :-)